# Grab data from JSON file doesn't work

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I try to grab data from JSON (http://www.openligadb.de/api/getmatchdata/bl1/2014/15). I want to get every single game with the goals, location, team ...
I tried this but it won't work.

```
    let url = "http://www.openligadb.de/api/getmatchdata/bl1/2014/15"

    //parse url

    if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!) {

        if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: [])) as? NSDictionary {

             //handle json

        }
    }
```

It doesn't steps in the 2nd if-statement (`if let json = (try?...`).
I hope you could help me.

Edit get data of dictionaries:

```
                    //Data Team1
                    if let team1 = object["Team1"] as? NSDictionary {

                            if let name = team1["TeamName"] as? String {
                                print("Name Team1: \(name)")
                            }
                            if let logo = team1["TeamIconUrl"] as? String {

                                print("Logo Team1: \(logo)")
                            }

                            // Etc.

                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to understand your JSON structure: you have an array first, not a dictionary.

This array has dictionaries, each of them holding an array of dictionaries.

It may sound complex but it's actually simple, you just follow the structure of your JSON and decode the values with the correct type.

In JSON, an array starts with `[` and a dictionary starts with `{` (also, be careful not to confuse this JSON syntax with Swift's arrays and dictionaries one).

Your code could be something like this, for example:

```
do {
    let url = "http://www.openligadb.de/api/getmatchdata/bl1/2014/15"
    if let url = NSURL(string: url),
           JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url),
           jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: []) as? NSArray {
            for object in jsonArray {
                if let goalsArray = object["Goals"] as? NSArray {
                    // Each "goal" is a dictionary
                    for goal in goalsArray {
                        print(goal)
                        if let name = goal["GoalGetterName"] as? String {
                            print("Name: \(name)")
                        }
                        if let ID = goal["GoalID"] as? Int {
                            print("ID: \(ID)")
                        }
                        // Etc.
                    }
                }
            }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

UPDATE: you're almost there! But "Team1" is a dictionary, not an array. :)

Here's the solution:

```
do {
    let url = "http://www.openligadb.de/api/getmatchdata/bl1/2014/15"
    if let url = NSURL(string: url),
        JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url),
        jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: []) as? NSArray {
        for object in jsonArray {
            if let team1 = object["Team1"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let name = team1["TeamName"] as? String {
                    print("Name Team1: \(name)")
                }
                if let logo = team1["TeamIconUrl"] as? String {
                    print("Logo Team1: \(logo)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Ok, now I undestand how to get the data of a array. But how do I get the data of an dictionary for example the data of `"Team1"`?

Comment: It's already in my answer. :D The `for ... in ...` loops are working on the arrays, while the `if let xxx = yyy["zzz"] ...` are accessing the dictionaries. For example if `goal` is a dictionary, and you want to get the value of its key "GoalID", you access `goal["GoalID"]`.

Comment: Could you have a look at my edited question? Is this correct?

Comment: Ok, now I got it too. Thanks a lot for your help!